# resourceData returns null for microsoft graph API webhook for Sharepoint Online

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to set webhook notification for SharePoint Online drive using MS Graph API. The subscription is setup. Whenever I make any change in the drive by adding/deleting a file I get a notification but the resourceData is null. 
Is this standard behaviour?

```
{"value":[
   {"subscriptionId":"XXX",
      "clientState":"secretClientValue",
      "tenantId":"XXX",
      "resource":"drives/<id>/root",
      "resourceData":null,
      "changeType":"updated",
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2019-01-22T18:23:45.9356913+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: i have the same issue. still hunting for an answer. i guess one option is to use the notification as a trigger to make a delta request as described here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview.

Answer (score 0):

Not all resources return `resourceData` within the notification itself, OneDrive is one of these.

OneDrive will return the following properties:

```
{
  "subscriptionId": "string",
  "expirationDateTime": "datetime",
  "resource": "relative url",
  "clientState": "string optional",
  "changeType": "updated"
}
```

You can find the spesific documentation for this [entity here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/webhooknotification).

Answer (score 0):

add "includeResourceData": true in the payload

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).